# l20n: Why does IE fail to render HTML tags that translation string contains?

Tags: internet-explorer-11, l20n

L20n is really helpful when it comes to implementing a localization requirement in our web application project and works perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox and **almost** gets us there in Internet Explorer 11.

We are using HTML (which is supported) in the translation strings, they are formatted like this example:

"About `<strong>` a `</strong>`"

It works beautifully in Chrome and Firefox:

[Translation result in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAA6Y.png)

Unfortunately when I switched to Internet Explorer 11, getting this lovely sight on the same part of the page:

[Translation result in IE 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jtmi5.png)

We're not doing anything weird or super special, it's pretty basic implementation.

Question is - has anyone encountered this issue while working with l20n and if so - is there anything that can be done to get Internet Explorer to render tags in translation strings?

Comment: Can you stand up a functional example? I'm an engineer on the Edge team, and would love to look into this for you.

Comment: Hi @Sampson, apologies for late reply, was really busy after work :). Is there anything specific you would like me to flesh out? I will update the question with extra information you require.

Comment: Preferably just an example I can run in my browser. I'm not familiar with l20n, but if there's a running example someplace, I am more than happy to debug in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Ok, no worries, will do so - unfortunately got caught up in a pesky deployment at work and had no time to get around to doing this yet.

Comment: No rush; I'll be here and ready to assist 

Comment: I've created the sample site: [link](http://sites.krisfrukacz.name/l20nedge001/ ) Unfortunately was unable to amend my question as the rep limit prevents me from expanding my post to one with 3 links.  If you have got any questions, please do give me a shout here. Again, thanks for help!

Comment: Your demo appears to work in Edge just fine. http://i.stack.imgur.com/J4gGr.gif

Comment: Crickey, I just went through my dev machine at work and you're right - works on Edge perfectly fine. I've unintentionally misguided you as I am a dumbo, it turns out. It's IE11 in Edge Mode. Dumb dumb dumb - apologies and I'm back to drawing board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After help from @Sampson (cheers!) and pointing out that a) It was issue on IE11/Edge Mode not Edge b) IE11 does not support one of the HTML5 elements such as Template, I dug around a little bit before I was about to announce complete defeat and digging through l20n github pages:

[l20n compatibility](https://github.com/l20n/l20n.js/blob/master/docs/compat.md#polyfills-for-legacy-browsers)

- Using babel polyfill
- Using patched webcomponents HTMLTemplateElement polyfill (link provided on page

I added babel and modified polyfill js file and after quick deploy and nervous refresh, it appeared the solution worked. Testing it as we speak so that it doesn't cause issues with the app but all looks good so far.

I know this is a workaround but our IE traffic is small enough yet I was not able to give up on these users that would like to use what I am currently working on in Irish and coincidentally would end up using IE11.

Comment: Good for you for digging deeper into the issue, and for showing consideration to all of your users. +1

Comment: Thanks and yeah - it's the same with accessibility, just because IE is in minority, if we can try to sort out such small niggles, we should at least try :) Cheers again!

Answer (score 1):

Due to the lack of support for the `<template>` element in Internet Explorer 11, the following fails:

```js
// https://github.com/l20n/builds/blob/0d58a55afa6ae5aa868b8002fae5ee0e2124e35d/l20n.js#L94
var templateSupported = 'content' in document.createElement('template');
```

It's worth noting that [the l20n.js team doesn't consider IE to be supported](https://github.com/l20n/l20n.js/pull/64#issuecomment-221026094).

Comment: Hi @Sampson and thanks for your input. I've managed to find some compatibility notes on l20n github page - I managed to resolve (or rather workaround) the issue using, as suggested by them, babylon-polyfill and modified  HTMLTemplateElement polyfill.